# C++ --- Polymorphic Deep copy

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, deep-copy

Is it possible to perform polymorphic deep copy without implementing copy constructors? (One of the TAs said it wouldn't be necessary to implement copy constructors)

**"Suppose you wish to be able to copy an expression object. The problem is that if all you have is an Expression pointer, you don't know what kind of object you actually have, much less what types of objects its fields may be pointing at. Devise a way, given an Expression pointer, to produce an exact (deep) copy of the object it points at."**

The Base Class **Expression** has no field.
But one of the subclasses contain an integer field, and another subclass contain a **Expression Pointer** field.

I tried creating this virtual method for each derived object:

```
virtual ExpressionBinaryOper *clone() const
{return new ExpressionBinaryOper(*this);}
```

ExpressionBinaryOper Class:

```
class ExpressionBinaryOper : public Expression {
    public:
ExpressionBinaryOper(Expression *left, Expression *right, const string 
    &op);
~ExpressionBinaryOper();
virtual ExpressionBinaryOper *clone() const
  {return new ExpressionBinaryOper(*this);}
void set(string name, int v);
void unset(string name);
string evaluate();
string prettyprint();

private:
    Expression *left;
    Expression *right;
    string oper;
};
```

And making the clone:

```
 Expression *theCopy = exp->clone(); //exp is a Expression pointer.
```

But after deleting the "clone pointer", exp is deleted too.

Comment: did you just get this execise? This isnt the first question on that topic today ;)

Comment: They probably want you to figure it out on your own instead of having us tell you. Hint: What can you do with an Expression pointer that still acts on the derived object and not just on the Expression? Use that to implement your copying.

Comment: Is part of the assignment, I tried Clone method, but it seems like clone method assumes the existence of cpy constructors.

Comment: if you tried something and it didnt work, you better show the code ([mcve]) because as it stands the question is a bit too broad

Comment: *The Base Class Expression has no field.*  But it would then have to have some interesting functions, perhaps even virtual ones?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a copy constructor. You just need some way of constructing the copy object in the correct state which a non-copy constructor might be able to do.

Comment: Please see the update. I can achieve the copy, but after deleting the clone, the original pointer is also gone.

Comment: How did you determine that "exp is deleted"?

Comment: I tried to use exp after deleting "the clone", but got a seg fault

Comment: @Frank That does not imply that anything has been deleted. Again, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That is because you didn't follow the rule of 0/5. In short if you manually write any of the special member functions copy/move constructor/assignment operator or destructor you must do so for all of them. I suspect your copy constructor is either implicit or just copies the pointer when it was supposed to make a deep-copy (clone) of that pointer.

Comment: @nwp But constructors cannot be virtual. How can I create constructors?

Comment: You don't need to create a constructor. You are already calling the most derived (copy) constructor (`ExpressionBinaryOper::ExpressionBinaryOper`). You are not showing the code so it is hard to tell, but it seems like it performs a shallow copy and not a deep copy.

Comment: @nwp please see the update

Comment: You didn't manually define the copy constructor. That means the default copy constructor is used, which just copies all the members. Copying `left` and `right` is incorrect though, you need to `.clone()` them. You already have a suitable constructor that takes a `left`, `right` and `op`. You just have to call it with the right arguments.

Comment: got it! thank you! @nwp